# DASK: Typerrror: Column assignment doesn't support type numpy.ndarray whereas Pandas works fine

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dask

I'm using Dask to read in a 10m row csv+ and perform some calculations. So far it's proving to be 10x faster than Pandas.

I have a piece of code, below, that when used with pandas works fine, but with dask throws a type error. **I am unsure of how to overcome the typerror**. It seems like an array is being handed back to the dataframe/column by the select function when using dask, but not when using pandas? But I don't want to switch the whole thing back to pandas and lose the 10x performance benefit.

This answer is the result of some help of some others on Stack Overflow, however I think that question has deviated far enough from the initial question that this is altogether different. Code below.

**PANDAS: Works**
Time Taken excluding AndHeathSolRadFact: 40 seconds

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from timeit import default_timer as timer
start = timer()
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\i5-Desktop\Downloads\Weathergrids.csv')
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M')
df['Month'] = df['DateTime'].dt.month
df['Grass_FMC'] = (97.7+4.06*df['RH'])/(df['Temperature']+6)-0.00854*df['RH']+3000/df['Curing']-30


df["AndHeathSolRadFact"] = np.select(
    [
    (df['Month'].between(8,12)),
    (df['Month'].between(1,2) & df['CloudCover']>30)
    ],  #list of conditions
    [1, 1],     #list of results
    default=0)    #default if no match



print(df.head())
#print(ddf.tail())
end = timer()
print(end - start)
```

**DASK: BROKEN**
Time Taken excluding AndHeathSolRadFact: 4 seconds

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.multiprocessing
import dask.threaded
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Dataframes implement the Pandas API
import dask.dataframe as dd



from timeit import default_timer as timer
start = timer()
ddf = dd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\i5-Desktop\Downloads\Weathergrids.csv')
ddf['DateTime'] = dd.to_datetime(ddf['Date'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M')
ddf['Month'] = ddf['DateTime'].dt.month
ddf['Grass_FMC'] = (97.7+4.06*ddf['RH'])/(ddf['Temperature']+6)-0.00854*ddf['RH']+3000/ddf['Curing']-30



ddf["AndHeathSolRadFact"] = np.select(
    [
    (ddf['Month'].between(8,12)),
    (ddf['Month'].between(1,2) & ddf['CloudCover']>30)
    ],  #list of conditions
    [1, 1],     #list of results
    default=0)    #default if no match



print(ddf.head())
#print(ddf.tail())
end = timer()
print(end - start)
```

**Error**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-86c08f38bce6> in <module>
     29     ],  #list of conditions
     30     [1, 1],     #list of results
---> 31     default=0)    #default if no match
     32 
     33 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3276             df = self.assign(**{k: value for k in key})
   3277         else:
-> 3278             df = self.assign(**{key: value})
   3279 
   3280         self.dask = df.dask

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\dask\dataframe\core.py in assign(self, **kwargs)
   3510                 raise TypeError(
   3511                     "Column assignment doesn't support type "
-> 3512                     "{0}".format(typename(type(v)))
   3513                 )
   3514             if callable(v):

TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type numpy.ndarray
```

**Sample Weathegrids CSV**

```
Location,Date,Temperature,RH,WindDir,WindSpeed,DroughtFactor,Curing,CloudCover
1075,2019-20-09 04:00,6.8,99.3,143.9,5.6,10.0,93.0,1.0 
1075,2019-20-09 05:00,6.4,100.0,93.6,7.2,10.0,93.0,1.0
1075,2019-20-09 06:00,6.7,99.3,130.3,6.9,10.0,93.0,1.0
1075,2019-20-09 07:00,8.6,95.4,68.5,6.3,10.0,93.0,1.0
1075,2019-20-09 08:00,12.2,76.0,86.4,6.1,10.0,93.0,1.0
```

Comment: Are you sure `np.select` isn't returning an array in the `pandas` case?  Maybe it returns an array, and `pandas` is ok with that.  You don't provide a [mcve] so I can't (readily) test your code (I have pandas, but not dask).

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj. I've added a sample weathergrids csv code block onto the bottom of the original question. If it's saved as a csv, and the code location updated those scripts should be copy/paste. The code works with pandas, but I'm hoping to get it working with dask due to the significant increase in speed it provides.

Comment: A google search on `dask column assignment` turns up a number of SO questions.  They tend to point to `assign`, as opposed to the `pandas` syntax that you are using: `https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.DataFrame.assign`.  Again I'm not a `dask` user, so can't help with the details.

Comment: Running this, the `select` does produce an array, with one element per row.  `pandas` is ok with creating a new column and filling it with values from the array.  The search that I just mentioned indicates that `dask` does not allow that, at least not with the same syntax.

Comment: Thanks @hpaulj I'll take a look at that

Comment: @hpaulj your clue on the search led me to finding a solution. It's not elegant, but it is functional .

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This answer isn't elegant but is functional.

I found the select function was about 20 seconds quicker on an 11m row dataset in pandas. I also found that even if I performed the same function in dask that the result would return a numpy (pandas) array. Dask inherently cannot accept this, but it is possible to transfer dataframes between dask and pandas.

So, I get the benefit of loading and date transforms in dask (4 seconds compared to 40 seconds in pandas), the benefits of select using pandas (40 seconds compared to 60 seconds in dask), and just need to accept that I'll be using more memory.

There's little loss in time by transforming between dataframes.

Finally, I had to make sure that I cleaned up dataframes as python wasn't cleaning up memory between test runs and just kept accumulating.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.multiprocessing
import dask.threaded
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Dataframes implement the Pandas API
import dask.dataframe as dd

from timeit import default_timer as timer
start = timer()
ddf = dd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\i5-Desktop\Downloads\Weathergrids.csv')
#print(ddf.describe(include='all'))

#Wrangle the dates so we can interrogate them
ddf['DateTime'] = dd.to_datetime(ddf['Date'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M')
ddf['Month'] = ddf['DateTime'].dt.month

#Grass Fuel Moisture Content
ddf['Grass_FMC'] = (97.7+4.06*ddf['RH'])/(ddf['Temperature']+6)-0.00854*ddf['RH']+3000/ddf['Curing']-30

#Convert to a Pandas DataFrame because dask was being slow with the select logic below
df = ddf.compute() 
del [ddf]

#ddf["AndHeathSolRadFact"] = np.select(
#Solar Radiation Factor - this seems to take 32 seconds. Why?
df["AndHeathSolRadFact"] = np.select(
    [
    (df['Month'].between(8,12)),
    (df['Month'].between(1,2) & df['CloudCover']>30)
    ],  #list of conditions
    [1, 1],     #list of results
    default=0)    #default if no match

#Convert back to a Dask dataframe because we want that juicy parallelism
ddf2 = dd.from_pandas(df,npartitions=4)
del [df]

print(ddf2.head())
#print(ddf.tail())
end = timer()
print(end - start)

#Clean up remaining dataframes
del [[ddf2]]
```

Answer (score 6):

I just had a similar problem, and I was able to get it to work by converting the `ndarray` into a Dask array.  I also had to ensure the number of partitions matched between the `ndarray` and the Dask DataFrame.

Comment: This didn't work for me -- at least when I try to assign the result of `dask.array.from_array(<ndarray>)` to a Dask dataframe column I get the error `TypeError: Column assignment doesn't support type Array`, so I would love to know how you got this to work.

Comment: If I try `dask.dataframe.from_array(<ndarray>)` then I don't get the above problem, but I get `ValueError: Not all divisions are known, can't align partitions. Please use set_index to set the index.` -- but... dask `Series` don't support `set_index`. So... ?

Answer (score 2):

Assigning series to Dask column works.

```
dask_df['col'] = pd.Series(list or array)
```

Comment: Good one. Thanks

Comment: Just tried this. The cell in which I run this completes, but when I call dask_df.head() afterwards, nothing happens. No computation is triggered on my cluster and the cell in my notebook containing ddf.head() doesn't complete. Any idea what might be going on here?

Answer (score 1):

For some reason that's not entirely clear to me yet, the above-mentioned solutions didn't work for me.

I ended up defining a function that does the column assignment per pandas dataframe and then mapping that function to all of my dask partitions.

```
def map_randoms(df):
    df['col_rand'] = np.random.randint(0,2, size=len(df))
    return df

ddf = ddf.map_partitions(map_randoms)
ddf.persist()
```

Comment: Looks pretty elegant. Any comment on the speed impact of this, if any?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try with adding .any() or .all() at the end of you np.select() statement?

```
df["AndHeathSolRadFact"] = np.select(
    [
    (df['Month'].between(8,12)),
    (df['Month'].between(1,2) & df['CloudCover']>30)
    ],  #list of conditions
    [1, 1],     #list of results
    default=0).all()    #default if no match
```

Answer (score -3):

EDITED:
I really have a elegant solution for you problem:-

```
from dask.array import from_array as fa
df.compute()['Name of you column'] = fa(the_list_you_want_to_assign_as_column)
```

Comment: This is the equivalent of saying "don't use dask".  As soon as he calls `.compute()` he is working with a regular pandas dataframe. The question is how to make it work with dask, right?