# DASK: Is there an equivalent of numpy.select for dask?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dask

I'm using **Dask** to load an 11m row csv into a dataframe and perform calculations. I've reached a position where I need conditional logic - If this, then that, else other.

If I were to use pandas, for example, I could do the following, where a numpy select statement is used along with an array of conditions and results. This statement takes about 35 seconds to run - not bad, but not great:

```
df["AndHeathSolRadFact"] = np.select(
    [
    (df['Month'].between(8,12)),
    (df['Month'].between(1,2) & df['CloudCover']>30) #Array of CONDITIONS
    ],  #list of conditions
    [1, 1],     #Array of RESULTS (must match conditions)
    default=0)    #DEFAULT if no match
```

What I am hoping to do is use **dask** to do this, natively, in a dask dataframe, without having to first convert my **dask** dataframe to a pandas dataframe, and then back again. 
This allows me to:
- Use multithreading
- Use a dataframe that is larger than available ram
- Potentially speed up the result.

**Sample CSV**

```
Location,Date,Temperature,RH,WindDir,WindSpeed,DroughtFactor,Curing,CloudCover
1075,2019-20-09 04:00,6.8,99.3,143.9,5.6,10.0,93.0,1.0 
1075,2019-20-09 05:00,6.4,100.0,93.6,7.2,10.0,93.0,1.0
1075,2019-20-09 06:00,6.7,99.3,130.3,6.9,10.0,93.0,1.0
1075,2019-20-09 07:00,8.6,95.4,68.5,6.3,10.0,93.0,1.0
1075,2019-20-09 08:00,12.2,76.0,86.4,6.1,10.0,93.0,1.0
```

**Full Code for minimum viable sample**

```
import dask.dataframe as dd
import dask.multiprocessing
import dask.threaded
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Dataframes implement the Pandas API
import dask.dataframe as dd

from timeit import default_timer as timer
start = timer()
ddf = dd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\i5-Desktop\Downloads\Weathergrids.csv')

#Convert back to a Dask dataframe because we want that juicy parallelism
ddf2 = dd.from_pandas(df,npartitions=4)
del [df]

print(ddf2.head())
#print(ddf.tail())
end = timer()
print(end - start)

#Clean up remaining dataframes
del [[ddf2]
```

Comment: Sequal to https://stackoverflow.com/q/58254236/901925

Comment: For clarity, that particular question relates to importing the resulting numpy select array into dask. 

This question seeks to explore whether there is a dask native select function so that no breakout to (pandas + numpy) is required. By avoiding that breakout and using a dask native select funciton we can avoid doubling the memory footprint, avoid moving between dataframe providers, avoid the conversion, and avoid problems where dataframe size exceeds available memory (a pandas issue). 

I have been unable to figure out dasks select, despite help suggesting its possible.

Comment: You might want to look at the code for `np.select`, https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L637-L738.  After broadcasting the inputs against each other, it does a masked `copyto` for each condition/value pair.  In effect `df["AndHeathSolRadFact"][df['Month'].between(8,12)] = 1`, etc.  It's not compiled.

Comment: I'm not quite familiar enough to understand what's happening there. The implication of it not being compiled is?

Comment: It means you should be able to replicate the function with other `numpy/pandas` functions, and by imitation with `dask` code, even if there isn't an exact `dask` `select` duplicate.

Comment: Righto, thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the answer I was able to come up with that was the most performant was:

```
#Create a helper column where we store the value we want to set the column to later. 
ddf['Helper'] = 1

#Create the column where we will be setting values, and give it a default value
ddf['AndHeathSolRadFact'] = 0

#Break the logic out into separate where clauses. Rather than looping we will be selecting those rows 
#where the conditions are met and then set the value we went. We are required to use the helper 
#column value because we cannot set values directly, but we can match from another column. 
#First, a very simple clause. If Temperature is greater than or equal to 8, make 
#AndHeathSolRadFact equal to the value in Helper
#Note that at the end, after the comma, we preserve the existing cell value if the condition is not met
ddf['AndHeathSolRadFact'] = (ddf.Helper).where(ddf.Temperature >= 8, ddf.AndHeathSolRadFact)

#A more complex example 
#this is the same as the above, but demonstrates how to use a compound select statement where 
#we evaluate multiple conditions and then set the value.
ddf['AndHeathSolRadFact'] = (ddf.Helper).where(((ddf.Temperature == 6.8) & (ddf.RH == 99.3)), ddf.AndHeathSolRadFact)
```

I'm a newbie at this, but I'm assuming this approach counts as being vectorised. It makes full use of the array and evaluates very quickly. 
Adding the new column, filling it with 0, evaluating both select statements and replacing the values in the target rows only added **0.2s** to the processing time on an 11m row dataset with npartitions = 4.

Former, and similar approaches in pandas took 45 seconds or so.

The only thing left to do is to remove the helper column once we're done. Currently, I'm not sure how to do this.

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for all your help. I think this is a very functional and extremely fast equivalent. It was your link to the select statement that eventually caused the penny to drop.

Comment: @MRocklin your link to the where documentation confirmed I was on the right path. I had to go looking elsewhere to work out the syntax and am not sure I would have worked it out from the documentation alone to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking to [dd.Series.where](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.Series.where)

Comment: Thanks. I more or less came across that this morning. I'm now trying to work out if I can set a string value based on another columns criteria. Slow progress.